# Namespaces autoloading_register uncaught error: class cannot be found

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I am trying to work with namespaces in my php file. Everything is working fine, till I put it online. 
Than I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'classes\Buddy\User' not found in /home/serafvc355/domains/imdbuddy.be/public_html/login.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/serafvc355/domains/imdbuddy.be/public_html/login.php on line 18

login.php

```
<?php

  include_once(__DIR__ . "/bootstrap.include.php");

  include_once 'autoload.php';


   if (!empty($_POST)) {

    //Put fields in variables
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
    //If both fields are filled in, check if the login is correct

      if (classes\Buddy\User::checkPassword($email, $password)) {
      $user = new classes\Buddy\User($email);

        if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['digit']) {
          if ($user->getActive() == 1) {
          $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
          header("Location: index.php");
         } else {
          $error = "Please confirm your account";
         }
      } else {
       $error = "Wrong Captcha";
      }
   } else {
     $error = "Sorry, we couldn't log you in.";
   }
 } else {

  //If one of the fields is empty, generate an error
  $error = "Email and password are required.";
  }
  }

 ?>
```

autoload.php

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $file = dirname(__DIR__) . '\\' . $className . '.php';
    $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);
    echo $file;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
    include $file;
}
});
```

User.php

```
<?php

  namespace classes\Buddy;

  class User
  {
   private $id
   ...
```

Files structure

```
classes > Buddy > User.php
```

Comment: _Probably not your problem_ But WHY put 2 backslashes into a string only to replace them strsight after `$file = dirname(__DIR__) . '\\' . $className . '.php';
    $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);`

Comment: You should also show us how you define the namespace in your `User.php` file, or we can't exclude it being a simple typo.

Comment: Stick with unix `/` everywhere, even if you are running on Windows, PHP will sort them out internally

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Since it's not completely unlikely that you sooner or later will use any third party library, why not set up composer and use their tried and tested autoloader?

Comment: I added the user.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it can be fixed by :

```
require 'autoload.php';
use classes\Buddy\User;
//in login.php
```

Then use like

```
if (User::checkPassword($email, $password))
```

But maybe the class is not loaded right or namespace is wrong not sure..